# How to get DIV Beneath Other DIVs in Hierarchy?

Tags: html, css, parallax

I'm having trouble with the order of layered DIV elements. I have a DIV `.lens-flare` that's at the bottom of the hierarchy in HTML. Yet when I `transform: translate` the position so it encompasses the entire parent DIV, it shows above elements that are above it in the hierarchy.

So I tried setting z-indexes, and then turned my `translate` into `translate3d`. Still I'm not able to get `.lens-flare` underneath `.top-nav-bar`, `.nav-bar`, or `.cta`.

Currently I have a `pointer-events: none` applied so I can at least click on the things underneath. But how can i actually move the `.lens-flare` layer under everything else successfully?

Here's my [CodePen](http://codepen.io/bmoneruiux/pen/mJbvQv/) for the project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elements rendered later are considered being closer to the screen than the elements rendered before them.

Z-index is the answer if you want to change this, you just need to remember z-index works only with elements that are positioned.

```
.lens-flare
  position: relative
  z-index: 1

.nav-bar, .top-nav-bar, .cta
  position: relative
  z-index: 2
```

Your corrected codepen: http://codepen.io/sEvher/pen/doyWoW

Comment: Note that since the OP is using the `transform` property, that defines a new stacking layer (analogous to `position: relative`).  Your fix will work without `position: relative` though adding it does not hurt the solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I didn't know about the "rendered-later = closer-to-screen". Although I guess it does make sense. I thought the hierarchy dictated the layer order. Applied and saved!

Comment: @MarcAudet explicit is better than implicit when it comes to explaining, I guess :>